# How to position this image next to text?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align my avatar/logo with the website title (side by side). How would I accomplish this?

```css
html {
    background: #bdb4c1;
}

#logo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

hr {
    border: 0;
    color: red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #101010;
}

body {
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 1000px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background: #fafafa;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    
}

h1, h3 {
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #272727;
}

p {
    color: #383838;
}
```

```html
<body>
    
    <div id="title">
        <img id="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/nm1i0Yo.png" alt="some_text" style="width:width;height:height;">
        <h1>JOSH BAKOS</h1>
    </div>
    
    <hr>
    
    <h3>INFORMATION</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    
    <h3>EXPERIENCE</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        
    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    
    <h3></h3>
</body>
```

Comment: Change the separate html/css parts to a working [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Done, thanks for correcting that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<img>` and `<h1>` tag cannot be aligned because `<h1>` is a [block](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp) element.
By default, block elements are displayed below the previous html element (i.e. below your `<img>` here).

There are many possible solutions. A simple one could be to move the `<img>` tag inside the `<h1>`:

```
<h1><img id="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/nm1i0Yo.png" alt="some_text" style="width:width;height:height;">JOSH BAKOS</h1>
```

Comment: Nice solution, +1 from me here :) I added another optional solution (using css to change the `H1` element to inline-block. You can check it too.

Comment: Thanks! In this particular context, my solution is more simple _but_ your solution is very useful when, for example, you need to display blocks next to each other. Therefore, your post is adding value here! :)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to set the `h1` inside the `#title` to inline-block (this way you can also control their vertical-alignment):

```css
html {
    background: #bdb4c1;
}

#logo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

hr {
    border: 0;
    color: red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #101010;
}

body {
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 1000px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background: #fafafa;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    
}
#title * {
  vertical-align: top;
}
#title h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0;
}
h1, h3 {
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #272727;
}

p {
    color: #383838;
}
```

```html
<body>
    
    <div id="title">
        <img id="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/nm1i0Yo.png" alt="some_text" style="width:width;height:height;">
        <h1>JOSH BAKOS</h1>
    </div>
    
    <hr>
    
    <h3>INFORMATION</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    
    <h3>EXPERIENCE</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        
    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    
    <h3></h3>
</body>
```

Comment: What does the '*' mean in #title *?

Comment: All elements that are inside the `#title` element

Comment: Is is necessary to have the `#title h1` in the CSS? What are the 2 lines: `display: inline-block;` and `margin-top: 0;` doing?

Comment: the inline-block is what changes the `h1` element from blocking to inline-block (this way it doesn't go to the next line). the `margin-top: 0` makes removes the default margin the `h1` tag has (so it will be aligned to the top)